Nilpotent Lie algebra decomposed into direct sum of root spaces for a torus
In this article Solvable complete lie algebras. I written by Meng Dao Ji and Zhu Lin Sheng. They use a decomposition using root systems, but when I searched about the Root systems I found that it is used in the framework of the semi-simple Lie Algebra.
For more clarification, they wrote:

Let $n$  be a nilpotent Lie algebra, $h$ be an abelian subalgebra of
$Dern$ such that all elements of  $h$  are semisimple linear
transformations of  $n$.  $h$  is called a torus on $n$.  Obviously,
$n$  is  decomposed  into  a  direct  sum of  root  spaces  for  $h$:
$n=\sum_{\beta \in h^*}n_{\beta}$ where $h^*$ is the dual space of
$h$; $n_{\beta}=\{x\in n| a.x=\beta(a)x \forall a\in h\}$.
If  $h$ is the maximal torus on  $n$,  we  let $\Delta=\{\beta \in h^*
> |n_{\beta}\neq 0 \}$ be the root system if $n$ associated to $h$.

They said "Obviously" but I don't know how they wrote all that; for me, it is far from obvious!
Can someone explain?

This follows from the hypothesis that $\mathfrak{h}$ acts semisimply. Concretely, what you need to show is that if linear maps $X_1, \dots X_n$ are 1) diagonalizable and 2) commute, then they are simultaneously diagonalizable. (Consider the action of each one on the eigenspaces on the others.)

The non-trivial part here might be to show that those "roots" (I would call them "weights" for the time being) actually satisfy the axioms of a root system for $h$ being a maximal torus. But the preparatory fact that we have a weight space decomposition follows as in @QiaochuYuan's comment. (In an earlier comment I had overlooked the assumption that $h$ is abelian; I believe Bourbaki somewhere makes more general statements even if $h$ is only nilpotent, not necessarily abelian, and the actions are not necessarily semisimple (so we look at generalized weight spaces).)
